# Algebra with exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = 4^x$ then show the value of $$f(x+1) - f(x)$$ in terms of $f(x)$.

I know the answer is $3f(x)$ because 
$f(x+1)$ means that it is $4^x$ multiplied by 4 once more, which minus one is 3.

The question: How do I show this process algebraically? (Hints only please) I have tried using ln() functions to remove the powers to no avail.

$$\ln(f(x)) = x\ln(4)$$ 
$$\ln(f(x+1)) = (x+1)\ln(4) = x\ln(4) + \ln(4)$$
$$\ln(f(x+1)) = \ln(f(x)) + \ln(4)$$

from here I don't know how to remove the natural logs to replace $f(x+1)$. What is a different approach I should use?

Comment: You are overthinking this. Your "I know the answer" is the answer. The words that follow say, correctly, that $4^{x+1} - 4^x = 4 \times 4^x - 4^x = 3 \times 4^x = 3f(x)$.

Comment: Oh dear, thank you for your time anyway!....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: $$f(x+1) = 4^{x+1} = 4^x\cdot 4=...$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the solution, but maybe try to solve beforehand

Good luck :)

$$\begin{align}
f(x+1)-f(x) &= 4^{x+1}-4^x \\[1ex]
 & = 4^x\cdot 4-4^x \\[1ex]
 & = f(x)\cdot 4-f(x) \\[1ex]
 & = 4f(x)-f(x) \\[1ex]
 & = 3f(x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = f(x)$. You want $f(x+1) - f(x)$ to be in terms of $y$, so you need to replace $x$ with an expression of $y$.

This expression is the inverse function of $f(x)$: $$x=f^{-1}(y)=\log_4y$$

Therefore, $$f(x+1) - f(x)=f(f^{-1}(y)+1)-f(f^{-1}(y))$$

Simplify this expression to get $3y$.